# How can you connect an iPhone to a Mac via Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is is possible for an iPhone application I'm writing to connect to a Mac via Bluetooth?  We don't have direct access to the Bluetooth API, so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible at least officially.